# Apply CSS class to dynamic table data

Tags: php, css, dynamic

I have a MySQL database with 35 different columns labeled 1-35. The data is displayed in a dynamic table. I am looking for the PHP code that would allow me to apply a CSS class to specific cells based on what is returned inside them.

EXAMPLE: Column 1 can return either TRUE or FALSE value. If a TRUE value is returned, I want to give that cell a different background color, or highlight it.

I have the CSS class as:

```
.highlight {
background-color: #FC0;
}
```

After the CSS class has then been applied to the specific cells from columns 1-35, I would like the PHP code that can total the number of highlighted cells in the column labeled TOTAL.

Can't seem to find the PHP code to tie all this together. If someone could advise, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: How are you currently emitting your tables?

Comment: I know you said that you wanted this done using PHP, but isn't this better suited for JavaScript, jQuery, or CoffeeScript?

Comment: @Edwin The asker's using the result's of a MySQL query to dictate how the page is styled. If you're already using PHP to output the content, might as well have it output the styles while you're at it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td class="<?php if ($row['item'] == TRUE)
{
    echo 'highlight';
    $highlights++;
}
else
{
    echo 'no_highlight';
}
?>"><?php echo $row['item'];?></td>
```

and then...

```
<td id="totalHighlights"><?php echo $highlights;?></td>
```

EDIT: Sample code...

```
<?php

//We've queried the database and passed the results into $result via mysql_fetch_assoc().

while ($row = $result)
{
    //Clear highlights and values arrays for each row.
    $highlights = array();
    $values = array();
    foreach($row as $entry)
    {
        if ($entry == TRUE)
        {
            //Put a truthy value into highlights array.
            array_push($highlights, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            //Put a falsey value into highlights array.
            array_push($highlights, 0);
        }

        //Push actual field value to values array.
        array_push($values, $entry);
    }
    echo '<tr class="row">';

    //Create cell with total highlights per row using the array_sum() of highlights.
    echo '<td class="row_total_highlights">'.array_sum($highlights).'</td>';

    //Create each value cell and populate them with each field value from values array.
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($values as $value)
    {
        echo '<td class="entry ';
        echo ($highlights[$i] == 1 ? 'trueClass' : 'falseClass');
        echo '">'.$value.'</td>';
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks... 1st part works great!  But for the 2nd part, it is only adding the total number of highlighted cells and storing the value in one specific cell.  I need each row to have its own unique total based on the total number of highlighted columns in that row.

Comment: Sorry, I had to move the "totalHighlights" column to the end of the table for each row to have its own unique number, but it still keeps a running total. EX: Row 1 has 2 highlighted cells, the number "2" displays in the total column. Row 2 has 3 highlighted cells, the number "5" displays in the total column. I need that to say "3". How would I make that happen?

Comment: Ok, no sweat. Simply set `$highlights` to zero at the beginning of each row, then append each row with `<td class="totalHighlights"><?php echo $highlights;?></td>`. Also, if you want these totals stored in a PHP array as opposed to HTML output, create an array called `$highlightsPerRow` or something like that, and at the end of each row, call `array_push($highlightsPerRow, $highlights);`.

Comment: Got it, Thanks! Setting $highlights to zero at the beginning of each row did the trick.  One more thing... How would I be able to move this totals column to the beginning of the table before the actual highlighted columns are calculated?

Comment: In that case, you'll want to process the data from your DB query before outputting to HTML, populating the `$highlightsPerRow` array mentioned above before drawing a single table cell. Then, using the same associative array fetched from your query, cycle through your data again to output for display as detailed above; only this time, keep a counter variable (e.g: `$i`) that increases incrementally with each row, and in the first cell for each row `echo $highlightsPerRow[$i];` to output the total number of highlights for the corresponding row.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I understand what you are saying, but have no idea how to write the php code.  Would you be able to show me what it looks like?

Comment: No problem. I've edited my answer above with some sample code.

Comment: The help you are providing is really appreciated, but I still can't get this column to the beginning of the table.  Where exactly do I insert the code you added above? I have queried the database using mysql_fetch_assoc after the rows have been generated and then inserted the new code. I also tried to put the code at the beginning, didn't work. Do I have to split it up? Do I have to pass a variable back somewhere? Would you be able to tell me the structure of how the elements should flow? What comes first, second, etc.

Comment: This code populates one table completely from the `tr` element down. I'd assumed that you had opening and closing `table` tags surrounding this block of code. If not, add them, and if you're still not getting the results you want, let me know and we'll work form there.

Comment: Ok, I did that.  It's dumping the entire database though. There are some columns I do not want displayed. Also, the highlighted cells have disappeared. And I do not see a column with TOTAL HIGHLIGHTS.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your database query. I'm guessing your SQL SELECT statement starts with `SELECT * FROM...`. Instead, explicitly specify the columns you want to select in your query. As for the lack of highlights, that was my bad. I've edited my answer with the necessary code to add the appropriate classes based on the truthiness of the enclosed value.